# Print Using Sequence of Consecutive and Non-Consecutive Numbers

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sequence, user-input

I have a list of serial numbers I need to cycle through in a macro. Most of the serial numbers are consecutive, but occasionally a few will be missing. For example, I might need to use serial numbers 500-510, 512-513, 516.

Is there a way to loop through a list like that? I'd really prefer not to have to write out every number, ex: 500, 501, 502, 503... because sometimes I could have hundreds of serial numbers.

Also, the list will change with every run, so I need to be able to ask the user for the list of serial numbers and then insert that list into the vba macro. Not sure how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't get much more complicated than your sample string one could refer to a `Range` object, e.g.:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "500-510,512-513,516"

For Each i In Range("A" & Replace(Replace(str, "-", ":A"), ",", ",A"))
    Debug.Print i.Row
Next

End Sub
```

It may be obvious there are limitations to this approach (both length-wise on concatenating a string that represents a `Range`, but also on potential numbers not represented through rows on a worksheet.

Maybe a little more solid would be:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "500-510,512-513,516"

For Each el In Split(str, ",")
    If InStr(1, el, "-") > 0 Then
        For x = Val(el) To Val(Right(el, InStrRev(el, "-") - 1))
            Debug.Print x
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print Val(el)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

As for your input string validation; You could look into `Like` operator or better, regular expressions.

Comment: Fine answer; FYI posted an alternative assigning numbers to an array +)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a function that accepts a string such as `"500-510,512-513,516"` and returns an array of numbers represented by that expression. I haven't fully tested the below, but it appears to do the job:

### Code

```
Function ParseNonContiguousRange(rangeExpr As String) As Long()
  Dim tokens As Variant, token As Variant
  Dim rangeStart As Long, rangeEnd As Long, count As Long, i As Long, index As Long
  tokens = Split(rangeExpr, ",")

  'First pass: count numbers in range

  For Each token In tokens
    If InStr(token, "-") Then
      rangeStart = CLng(Split(token, "-")(0))
      rangeEnd = CLng(Split(token, "-")(1))
      count = count + rangeEnd - rangeStart
    Else
      count = count + 1
    End If
  Next token

  Dim result() As Long
  ReDim result(count + 1)

  'Second pass: populate range

  For Each token In tokens
    If InStr(token, "-") Then
      rangeStart = CLng(Split(token, "-")(0))
      rangeEnd = CLng(Split(token, "-")(1))
      For i = rangeStart To rangeEnd
        result(index) = i
        index = index + 1
      Next i
    Else
      result(index) = CLng(token)
      index = index + 1
    End If
  Next token
  ParseNonContiguousRange = result
End Function

Sub TestParseNonContiguousRange()
  Dim output() As Long
  output = ParseNonContiguousRange("500-510,512-513,516")
  For Each i In output
    Debug.Print i
  Next i
End Sub
```

### Output

```
 500 
 501 
 502 
 503 
 504 
 505 
 506 
 507 
 508 
 509 
 510 
 512 
 513 
 516
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get an array of numbers in different sequences**

In addition to JvDv's valid answer an alternative approach assigning items to a 0-based **1-dim array** which could be used for further processing:

```
Sub GetArrayOfNumbers()
Dim numbers As String: numbers = "500-510,512-513,516"

ReDim tmp(10000)                                 ' provide for enough items in temp array
Dim number
For Each number In Split(numbers, ",")           ' check each number or pair of numbers
    Dim pair: pair = Split(number & "-" & number, "-")
    Dim i As Long, counter As Long
    For i = Val(pair(0)) To Val(pair(1))
        tmp(counter) = i: counter = counter + 1  ' add number to temporary array
    Next
Next number
ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To counter - 1)             ' reduce to exact items count

Debug.Print Join(tmp, ",")                       ' (optional) display in VB Editor's Immediate Window
' ~> 500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,512,513,516
End Sub
```

**Methodical hints**

In order to avoid distinguishing between single numbers and a number range, I changed any number token to a pair of numbers by re-adding the same token (prefixed by "-") to itself which simplifies splitting and the eventual assignment loop.

So splitting the last token `"516-516"` will allow to collect the relevant array item in a single loop step, whereas the additional appendix doesn't matter in the actual pairs of numbers (as splitting the redundant string `"500-510-500-510"` results in a correct values `pair(0)` = 500 and `pair(1)`=510, too).