# Is there a function or VBA that can read multiple strings within a single cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table that has production numbers for a machine I run. They all start with the letter O and there are 4 different production types, e.g., O0000, O1000, O2000, and O3000. I have a table to the side that tells me what the next production number is for each type.

Sometimes, I need a couple production numbers for one project. I've used simple MID and RIGHT functions to split the production number into two columns and a MAXIFS function to determine the largest production number per type to determine what my next production number is.

[image: Table mentioned earlier]

The only problem is that I am planning to have 2+ production numbers in future projects. So, is there a function (or VBA code) that can read each 5 character string beginning with O in a cell and accurately determine the largest value without needing to create new columns ? I prefer to see all the production numbers for the project in one consistent column for readability.

The last row is an example of a project with 3 production numbers. Ideally, the next Lathe production number should read O0124.

If you have any questions, let me know and I'll try my best to answer.

Comment: For reference, I pulled the first character in the Data Left and Data Right columns to fill the Data Type column, which then references the table to the side to determine the Production Type

Comment: String manipulation functions like `Split()` and `Mid()` could probably help you achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: Whitch are the rules to calculate the "Data Type" when have three of four production numbers? This is critical because you need the Max+1 of each Data Type. Will the order of the production numbers -in a cell- play a role in the calculation of the Data Type?

Comment: :-) comparable post needing only minor changes: [..sequence of consecutive and non-consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542020/print-using-sequence-of-consecutive-and-non-consecutive-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to make it work with worksheet formulas, maybe someone else can revise my other answer. Here is a solution with a custom function.

The function is named `LARGEPROG` and takes 3 arguments: the range containing the text you want to search, the minimum value you want to find, and the maximum value you want to find.

If you want the O2000's you would use `=LARGEPROG(A1:A5,2000,3000)`

```
Function LARGEPROG(prog_text As Range, minimum_value As Long, maximum_value As Long) As Long

Dim rg As Range
Dim rgString As String
Dim MaxValue As Long
Dim vValue As Variant

For Each rg In prog_text
    
    'Remove "O"
    rgString = Replace(rg, "O", "")
    
    'Choose delimiter
    If InStr(rgString, "-") Then
        delim = "-"
    ElseIf InStr(rgString, ",") Then
        delim = ","
    Else
        delim = ""
    End If
    
    'Split range text
    arr = Split(rgString, delim)
    
    'Check if each value is within range
    For Each vValue In arr
        If vValue >= minimum_value And vValue < maximum_value And vValue > MaxValue Then MaxValue = vValue
    Next vValue

Next rg

LARGEPROG = MaxValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTITUTE` will get rid of the letter "O".

`TEXTSPLIT` will split the string by the "-" or ",".

`NUMBERVALUE` will turn the text into a number.

`MAX` will pick the highest number.

Then you need 2 different formulas, depending on whether your text is separated by "-" or ",". Or use `LET` to determine which delimiter to use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A1)),
MAX(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"O",""),"-"))),
MAX(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"O",""),","))))
```

Or

```
=LET(DELIM,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A1)),"-",","),
MAX(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"O",""),DELIM))))
```

Edit:
More complicated if you need the maximum value from the range in a single cell but this should do it:

```
=MAX(BYROW(A1:A2,LAMBDA(PROGRAMTEXT,LET(DELIM,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",PROGRAMTEXT)),"-",","),
MAX(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(PROGRAMTEXT,"O",""),DELIM)))))))
```

Comment: Can this work for a range ? I'll need it to find the max within the whole column

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Have edited the answer above.

Comment: I have no idea what it's doing but it is working, so thank you ! One last question: right now, it's taking the max of each string, is there a way to take the max of only one type of program, e.g., O1000's or O2000 production numbers.

Comment: Seems like adding `MAXIFS` to the formula doesn't work, so I don't know if it can be done with formulas. I've added a second answer with a custom function in VBA.